# Get access google spreadsheet (saved into google drive account) from a java google app engine (servlet)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I really stuck here. I want to access to a google spreadsheet from an google app engine (with java, using servlet because the idea is read the information from that spreadsheet, saved in my google drive account, and shows via "jsp" to a limited users number, here in my company).

Of course i've already create my project in the "google cloud developer console" i got the "project id" fourth-case-XXXX, etc . Until this step I understood everything and went well.

I´ve been looking thousands of example here , on google, etc.For everything I read I understand that: I must to create a "OAuth2 credential" (reason why i created OAuth2 credential in the "Api and authentication" in my developer console of course (i got a json with a auth_uri, client_secret, client_id, etc, etc).

From what I've read just need the client_secret and client_id. But following this tutorial ([link](http://soatutorials.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html)) i got this error "oauth_token does not exist.". In other tutorial i´v read that is not necessary use "OAuth2" in app engine. I am very dizzy.

The only that i want is a simple java servlet (nothing complex, following good practices, I do not care) that read data from google spreadsheet (saved into my google drive account) and showing through a "jsp", at least I am content to accept for receiving the spreadsheet data on my servlet and later I will imagine how to show

I´m ussing eclipse luna, i got installed "gdata java api", "google app engine as localhost", etc (all properly installed, running without errors). to create the ambient I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse) tutorial

Some questions: 
1-The spreadsheet need to be published? (menu: file->publish to the web). to get acces from an app engine?
2-To test my code (and look if i got access to the spreadhsheet) in mandatory Uploading to Google App Engine  (http://.appspot.com/guestbook)  or i can try with "localhost"?

i will upload my code, attached image etc. I apologize for my nasty code but now I need to solve this issue

Thanks all

```
public void callingSpreadsheetTest2() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("callingSpreadsheetTest2");
    HttpTransport  transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleOAuthParameters oAuthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
    oAuthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CLIENT_ID);
    oAuthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);

    OAuthHmacSha1Signer signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();
    GoogleOAuthHelper oAuthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(signer);

    oAuthParameters.setScope(SCOPES);

    try{
        oAuthHelper.getUnauthorizedRequestToken(oAuthParameters);
    }catch (OAuthException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String requestUrl = oAuthHelper.createUserAuthorizationUrl(oAuthParameters);
    System.out.println(requestUrl);
    System.out.println("Please visit the URL above to authorize your OAuth "
     + "request token.  Once that is complete, press any key to "
     + "continue...");

    try{
        System.in.read();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    oAuthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH);
    String token = null;
    try{
        token = oAuthHelper.getAccessToken(oAuthParameters);
    }catch(OAuthException  e){
        e.printStackTrace(); //---->Attention: HERE I GOT toke=null (oauth_token does not exist.)
    }
    System.out.println("OAuth Access Token: " + token);
    System.out.println();

    URL feedUrl = null;

    try{
        feedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SpreadsheetService spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService("GAppEngineProj");

    try{
        spreadsheetService.setOAuthCredentials(oAuthParameters, signer);
    }catch(OAuthException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = spreadsheetService.getFeed(feedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
        if(spreadsheets != null) {            
              for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
                  System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
              }
         }
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also my class "com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService" NOT have the method setOAuth2Credentials only [service.setOAuthCredentials(parameters, signer);]

Once again thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're using code for the OAuth1 protocol, which is deprecated. You should use OAuth2 instead.

An App Engine application comes with a very convenient `AppIdentityService` ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/)) which allows your application to generate OAuth2 tokens as if the application had an email in the format `your-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`.

All you have to do is share your spreadsheet with this email using the Google Drive / Google Spreadsheets UI. In your case the email would be `fourth-case-XXXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Then, in the code, do this :

```
AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
String accessToken = appIdentityService.getAccessToken(Collections.singleton(SPREADSHEET_SCOPE)).getAccessToken();
GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential();
googleCredential.setAccessToken(accessToken);
spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService("MyApp");
spreadsheetService.setOAuth2Credentials(buildCredential());
```

Then you are ready to use your `spreadsheetService` to read data.

NB : this code was written with the GData library version 1.47.1 .

Comment: I appreciate your help, sorry my mistake I am beginner. what kind of object is "appIdentityService" ???

---> AccessTokenRequest atr = GTAuthorizationCode.createAccessTokenRequest (OAuth2, authorizationCode, redirect_uri); ????

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the `appIdentityService` instantiation code. I have edited the code with this info. `AppIdentityService`is a class provided by App Engine.